# Do I need to build LLDB locally to use C++ interface?

Tags: xcode, llvm, lldb

I have XCode 5 installed, I can use command-line lldb just fine. Now I want to create my own application that will link with LLDB C++ interface. I tried to search through the XCode package and found no .a archives, no headers. Does this mean I need to build LLDB locally (and go through the signing process)?

Comment: by "interface", do you mean API? And what "signing process"?

Comment: @H2CO3 I mean linking with LLDB and using http://lldb.llvm.org/cpp_reference/html/annotated.html. Signing is required on Mac so the debugger can actually debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is indeed correct that there are no header files included in the LLDB.framework that comes with Xcode

With that said, you have two possible avenues:

- build LLDB from source, as you said, and then use the built ToT to write your app
- obtain the headers from our open source repository and put them  in the magical location in the Xcode-provided LLDB.framework and that should enable you to link successfully against whatever LLDB you have.

The incantation should be to make an Headers folder in LLDB.framework/Versions/A and copy all the **PUBLIC** headers from our sources into there (you want LLDB.h, all the SB*.h files and lldb-defines,enumerations,forward,public,types,versioning.h) - then go into LLDB.framework and make a symlink named Headers to Versions/Current/Headers

Just an FYI - the public API (SB*.h) is all that is pretty much supported and guaranteed to be relatively stable. If you start trying to use the private layer (lldb_private::*), you are going to be on your own and breakages might be fairly frequent as the internals of the debugger evolve

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently trying to build it. Do you know by chance if LLDB 3.3 cannot be built with XCode5? I tried it yesterday and it failed apparently due to some issue with headers in platform SDK, I haven't got the time to look further.

Comment: On Enrico's FYI, I want to be a little stronger.  If you use the lldb_private API's you will be exposed not just to changes in the API but to changes in the sizes of all the objects underlying it.  Your code will be pretty much guaranteed only to work with the version of lldb you built at the same time you built your code.  OTOH, we are happy to add useful API's to the SB API set, so if you find anything that is in the lldb_private API's but not in the SB API's, feel free to add it and submit a patch to the lldb-dev team.  You can find out more about this by going to lldb.llvm.org.

Comment: Honestly I am not sure. 3.3 and similar are LLVM revision numbers and don’t usually mean a lot for LLDB. LLDB tends to go with its own version numbers (e.g. LLDB-300.x.y), so it would be interesting to know which (if any) LLDB version was picked for 3.3, or if it ended up just being a random SVN revision.

Comment: LLDB framework included in Xcode may have some Apple's own patch and very unlikely to be compatible with current open sourced LLDB public API. Apple is providing their LLDB source code, but it's very old version (310.x), and doesn't seem to work with current version (320.x) from Xcode. (It didn't work with my quick test, but I may missing something)